# Threads creation

Tags: c#, multithreading

Please have a look at the following code.
I am getting my head around MultiThreading in C#.
The example was taken from some manual.
In my Main function I try to create three threads.

Could you please tell me how two Threads (with errors) should be properly created?
Thank you!

```
using System;    
using System.Threading;    


public static class MonitorMethodAccess
{
   private static int numericField = 1;
   private static object syncObj = new object();

public static object SyncRoot
{
    get { return syncObj; }
}

public static void IncrementNumericField()
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(syncObj, 250))
    {
        try
        {
            ++numericField;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(syncObj);
        }

    }
}

public static void ModifyNumericField(int newValue)
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(syncObj, 250))
    {
        try
        {
            numericField = newValue;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(syncObj);
        }
    }
}

public static int ReadNumericField()
{
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(syncObj, 250))
    {
        try
        {
            return (numericField);
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(syncObj);
        }
    }

    return (-1);
}
```

}

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread aaa = new Thread(MonitorMethodAccess.IncrementNumericField);
        Thread bbb = new Thread(MonitorMethodAccess.ModifyNumericField(12);//error
        Thread ccc = new Thread(MonitorMethodAccess.ReadNumericField);//error

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be a copy-paste error, but you're missing a close `)` in your `Program.Main`. Should be `Thread bbb = new Thread(MonitorMethodAccess.ModifyNumericField(12));`

Comment: Do they still use the `.Start()` method to kick off threads?  (Even `aaa` looks like it would just sit there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread bbb = new Thread(()=>MonitorMethodAccess.ModifyNumericField(12));
Thread ccc = new Thread(() => MonitorMethodAccess.ReadNumericField());
```

But if you want to return values from threads as in your third thread, you should think to use [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

Comment: I'd say Tasks should be used except for very rare specialized cases, not just when you want to return a value.

Comment: It compiles and works fine. I am struggling to understand how lambda expression works here... Any advice please?

Comment: Your second thread takes a parameter, therefore you should start it with *ParameterizedThreadStart*, third one isn't *void*. So I replaced all of them with `delegate void SomeAction()` using lambdas (encapsulating those detail)

Answer (score 2):

The question is purely syntactical. When you write

```
MonitorMethodAccess.IncrementNumericField
```

this expression evaluates to the method itself. When you write

```
MonitorMethodAccess.IncrementNumericField()
```

this expression evaluates to the *result of the invocation of the method*, in this case `void`. You cannot pass `void` to a thread, it expects a method or a delegate, and one that does not take any parameters. Now the question is how to achieve passing a method and some specific parameters? As pointed out by I4V, you can wrap it in a lambda expression, which itself does not take parameters:

```
Action methodInvocation = (Action)(() => MonitorMethodAccess.ModifyNumericField(12));
Thread bbb = new Thread(methodInvocation);
```

Comment: Note: Threads do take methods with a single `object` parameter (ie: ParameterizedThreadStart).  Also, ThreadStart may be a non-static class method of this or a different class.  This is a holdover from when Action, Task and lambda didn't exist in C#.